# Users/company/Desktop/app/DemoApp/Pods/Bolts/Bolts/iOS/BFAppLink.m:11:9: 'BFAppLink_Internal.h' file not found

Tags: swift3, cocoapods, ios10

I am trying to build my project. And the build is failed due to this error.

`Users/company/Desktop/app/DemoApp/Pods/Bolts/Bolts/iOS/BFAppLink.m:11:9: 'BFAppLink_Internal.h' file not found`

I have tried different solutions. No answers on stackoverflow are helpful for me.

**Any help would be appreciated!!**

Answer (score 2):

Install [cocoapods](https://cocoapods.org/) and then run `pod install` from the command line in the directory containing your xcode project file.

Comment: It is still same.

Answer (score 2):

You need to Clear CocoaPods cache, re-download and re-install all pods.

Answer (score 1):

Encounter same issue here and fixed!
Just need to delete the whole Pods directory, keep the Podfile and then run pod install.